# Phone Number Validation

Tags: validation

I need to write a validation rule for phone numbers to only start with 0 and be 11 digits long, no more, no less.

This is what I have so far below: At the moment, it is accepting 10 digits and I am able to save the record with only 10 digits. I need it to be 11 digits, no more, no less but I'm finding it difficult to correct it. Would really appreciate the help.

Many thanks

```
AND(
    OR(
        ISBLANK(Phone),
        NOT(REGEX(Phone, "^(0)[1-9]{1}([0-9]{8,9})$"))
    ),
    OR (
        Profile.Name = "Sales Agent",
        Profile.Name = "Field Sales Agent",
        Profile.Name = "Field Service Agent",
        Profile.Name = "Lead Gen Agent",
        Profile.Name = "TEL Sales Agent",
        Profile.Name = "THS Sales Agent"
    )
)
```

Comment: What if you need to enter an extension in the phone number like "ext 123"?

Comment: No need for extension just straight up dial. Ext has a separate field @David Cheng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go low tech.

Add this to your `OR` statement:
`NOT(LEN(LastName) = 12)`

Ie:

```
OR(     
        NOT(LEN(Phone) = 11),
        ISBLANK(Phone),
        NOT(REGEX(Phone, "^(0)[1-9]{1}([0-9]{8,9})$"))
    ),
```

This has the benefit of be a whole lot easier to read than the regex, which you can still use to validate other stuff.

Comment: probably can remove the regex completely and use `ISNUMBER(Phone)` along with `BEGINS(Phone, '0')`

Comment: Yep, definitely. Regex in validation rules is just horrible. No debugging, strange syntax. Yeuch.

Comment: Thanks @CasparHarmer! Very useful

Answer (score 6):

The bit you're concerned with here is `NOT(REGEX(Phone, "^(0)[1-9]{1}([0-9]{8,9})$"))`

It's pretty much always a good idea to understand the tools that you're using (which is why I personally avoid using and giving copy/paste-able answers), so let's break down this regex. Understanding what the regex means should make it easier for you to identify and change the correct part of it.

- `^` = Search for the following starting at only the start of the string
- `(0)` = look for a 0 (enclosing it in parenthesis makes it a *capturing group* in most regex tools
- `[1-9]{1}` = look for exactly 1 (that's the `{1}` part) symbol that's between '1' and '9' (i.e. every digit except for 0)
- `([0-9]{8,9})` = another capturing group. This one looks for digits 0-9, and will match between 8 and 9 repeated digits
- `$` = the preceding expression must occur at the end of the string

`^<expression>$` is then "this expression must match the entire string"
`{x,y}` means "repeated between x times at least, and no more than y times"

counting up the characters you're expecting, you have

- Leading 0
- A single digit (1-9)
- 8 or 9 digits (0-9)

2 + 8 = 10, which is why your validation rule is allowing a 10-digit phone number

If you want precisely 11 digits, then you need to change that `{8,9}` so that it only accepts 9 digits for that part of your expression.

`{x}` means "only accept *exactly this many characters*", so `{9}` there should work.

Comment: There are other ways to enforce a length of 11, I just chose the easiest one. You could, for example, require that the 1-9 portion be precisely 3 digits long, and then reduce the 0-9 portion to be precisely 7. I guess the main point here is that if you want exact string length in a regex, you can't use a range like `{8,9}`

Comment: Thanks @Derek F. Very useful!